# I want to delete all files matching 'a.*' if the used disk space in /tmp exceeds 50%

Tags: unix, solaris, diskspace

I need to delete all files starting with 'a.' as soon as capacity of my /tmp exceeds 50% and this command should always run in background. I am new to Unix, so can someone help me.

Comment: Hi paul, i tried taking output of df -k and use if statement. but don't know much how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot you can do without costly forks and pipes to parse and match command output.
My suggestion is to use a command script like

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin   # Cron does not export any PATH.
case `df /tmp` in
    (* [5-9]?% *) rm -f /tmp/a.*
esac
```

This works independently of the column where the percentage used is output by `df`.
Note that this works for Use% values from 50% to 99%, but not 100% and above (which can happen due to the reserved space for the superuser). This is left as an exercise :-)

Now as for running this regularly, you can set `VISUAL=vi` and/or `EDITOR=vi` and then `crontab -e` will pop you into the editor you specified. Insert a line like

```
* * * * * /full/path/to/above/script
```

and save & exit. This will run the script once a minute. Once every ten minutes would be

```
0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /full/path/to/above/script
```

Make sure the script is executable with `chmod +x /full/path/to/above/script`.

Comment: Setting environment variables is done like this: `export VISUAL=vi` (for bourne shell) or `set VISUAL = vi` for tcsh. What does `echo $SHELL` say?

Comment: With the csh it would be `setenv VISUAL vi` - and ask your sysadmin to give you a proper shell: ksh, bash, zsh (best!).

Comment: jens even after setting Vi its not acepting common vi editors 799
:q!
?...Hey thanks now it works

Comment: Yes it does. Did you setenv both VISUAL and EDITOR to `vi` in lower case letters? Note that Unix is case sensitive almost everywhere.

Comment: hey jene..its showing following error on running....../bin/atul: syntax error at line 3: `(' unexpected

Comment: Ah, Solaris old style shell. Change  `$(df /tmp)` to `\`df /tmp\`` (i.e. use backticks!)

Comment: so this has to be changed for  (* [5-9]?% *) rm -f /tmp/a.* also?

Comment: No, just $(...). But if the shell complains about `(*` now, then make that line `*" "[5-9]?%" "*) rm -f /tmp/a.*;;`

Comment: thanks ..also is it required to keep 0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * /path > /dev/null

Comment: hi my crontab is not working .can I use this command and if it will run this in background  #!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
while :
do
case 'df /tmp' in
*" "[5-9]?%" "*) rm -f /tmp/af.*;;
esac

Comment: No, that'll run about hundred times per second and cause the wrath of your sysadmin. With the proper PATH, run `while sleep 60; do case \`df /tmp\` in *" "[5-9]?%" "*) rm -f /tmp/af.*; esac; done`

Comment: so does that mean that if I edit my script and run the script, it will run and check the disc space even after i logout of system?

Comment: No. Logging out sends a hangup signal to all scripts of the session in order to terminate them. Who is creating af.* files when you are logged out? Why should this script run unattended?

Comment: those are getting created by diffrent users logging externally. will nohop command work in this case?

Comment: It might sort of work, but only until the next reboot, which is why cron is the proper way to do this. Note that you can't delete other users' files in `/tmp` unless you have proper privileges.

Comment: I do have privilege and can delete them with rm command . i just tried nohup <scriptname> &, and if i do ps -a it shows myscript and its process. But if I logout and login again..ps -a doesent show that script?. Its OK with me if it works till reboot as again I can run that after reboot

Comment: You get what you asked for: -a Lists information about all processes most frequently requested: all those except session leaders and **processes not associated with a terminal**. Use -e instead.

Comment: Yup. Until it exits, someone kills it, or the machine reboots. Now I think it's time to upvote or accept this answer if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to help without giving you the answer. That way you get to learn some other stuff!

First you'll probably want to save a bunch of commands as a script and run it with something like cron.
You can do like `while true ; do rm a.* ; sleep 60 ; done` but it won't restart after a reboot. Cron jobs will.
That line of code runs every minute and deletes a.*. Change 60 down to 1 if you want it every second.
To make it more useful, look at your favourite command for disk space, use things like cut and grep to take certain fields and remove header lines (if there is no option to the basic space command just to output %space)
e.g.

```
[max@fedora ~]$ df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks   Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        4866748 202812   4419868   5% /tmp
[max@fedora ~]$ df /tmp | grep tmp| cut -c43-45
  5
```

Then you just need to look at some if statement syntax and you're away. Save the commands that you write into a file called "space_clear.sh" and then add space_clear.sh to cron to run every minute and you're away.
TOP TIP : While you're testing things out, do `ls a.*` instead of `rm a.*` and then if you get it horribly wrong, it's just showing you the files it would have deleted instead of deleting them! Remember, getting things wrong is learning.
(If you're really still stuck, read about if, then and fi for your preferred shell (bash/ksh csh/bourne). Stick in the df command with extras in back quotes with a comparison operator and 50 as part of the "if".)

Comment: hi max; I am unable to use crontab -e as I donn't know which editor this one is entering in ..for sure seems its not vi. Any ways i tried using following for running in background but this one is not working and also if statement is also showing error. Can you please help.while :
do
if [ df -k /tmp | grep tmp | cut -c48-50 -ge 50]
then
rm af?*
fi